# Unable to implement SSO in Salesforce

Tags: authentication, salesforce, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I am implementing service provider-initiated SSO for Salesforce where the service provider will be Salesforce and the identity provider will be a lambda code. The lambda code will allow a user after verifying the user's mobile number. Once the mobile number is verified a SAMLResponse will be sent by lambda.

I have configured SSO on Salesforce as below:-
[image]

I am also able to generate a valid SAML response and have validated it on Salesforce SAML validator as below:-

[image]

I have created a [login page](http://salesforce-sso-page.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com) that will be redirected from Salesforce.

I have also created an API to get a unique SAML response every time for the given federation ID as below:-
https://qodz4saz9a.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1/generate-saml-response?FederationID=rahul@xyz.com

URL for Salesforce login page is- https://im--partial.my.salesforce.com/.

After all this setup I am able to get redirected to the login page I have created from Salesforce by selecting "Log In with a Different Account" option and then selecting "Twilio" as below:-

[image]

Salesforce is redirecting to the login page with a SAMLRequest parameter in the URL as below:-

http://salesforce-sso-page.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/?SAMLRequest=fZJRc6IwFIX%2FC.....

I am not sure how to proceed from here and allow login to Salesforce from my login page. Once the user enters a mobile no and OTP, I am redirecting the user to below URL -

https://im--partial.my.salesforce.com?SAMLResponse=PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0i.....

Here I am using SAMLResponse as a query parameter to pass the base 64 encoded SAML response for login to Salesforce. But I am not sure if it is a correct way to authenticate and login to Salesforce.

After entering the OTP(test OTP is 1234) I am getting the below error.[image]

I am not at all using the **SAMLRequest** generated by Salesforce for generating the **SAMLResponse** for now.

I have gone through many documents but couldn't find a way to pass the SAMLResponse to Salesforce for login. Please let me know if anybody has any idea about it or if I am following the wrong steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SAML response is sent to the service provider in a specific "way", the protocol refers to this as a *binding*. In this case the expected binding is HTTP POST. With HTTP POST as your binding, the SAML response must be submitted in a body of HTTP request sent to the service provider via a POST method. The `Login URL` listed in the Single Sign-On Settings screen is the endpoint where the SAML response should be POSTed. It might look something like this:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: im--partial.my.salesforce.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: nnn
SAMLResponse=response
```

Do you need to worry about the SAML request? It depends on your workflow and desired end-user experience. The considerations that go into this decision deserve their own SO question. Meanwhile, take a look at [SAML Technical Overview](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/27819/sstc-saml-tech-overview-2.0-cd-02.pdf) for a summary of these workflows.

Last but not least, this whole sequence of authentication via your mobile number is supported by Salesforce [out of the box](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/identity-for-mobile-centric-customers/identity_mfi_basics) on some Salesforce products.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. You have answered all of my questions in detail. I haven't even thought of using POST. Also, thanks for your last point. I will check it.

Comment: If anyone else faces the same issue and want to know how to POST from the javascript code. Please check this - https://play.golang.org/p/b-td-FXz8Pm